# Receive (not forward) e-mail using Mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun

I want to use **Mailgun** to send/receive messages programatically via API.

BUT I need to have also some mailboxes available using **Thunderbird** or other mail client.

For example I want to have user mailboxes at:

- support@
- sales@
- admin@

And all other e-mails will be for API send/receive.

I can not forward my mail to GMail because I need to reply from the same address (sales@mydomain.com).

Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a limitation to using the routing feature and that is that if you delegate a domain to be used by Mailgun you cannot use it with an email client.
That means that, for example, if you want to route emails to `user@domain.com` and then still use that email address with your favourite email client (be it Thunderbird, Outlook or Gmail) you can't do it. That is because of the way you've configured your MX records (email records in your DNS).

When you use Mailgun's routing functionality you delegate MX records to mailgun, which receives your emails, parses them and routes them according to your preferences.

**So how do we solve your problem?**
What you can do instead is set up your MX record on a *subdomain*.

Using `subdomain.mydomain.com` and pointing its MX records to mailgun will allow you to receive and parse emails through Mailgun.

This way you can have:

- admin@subdomain.mydomain.com
- sales@subdomain.mydomain.com 
  etc
  will be handled by mailgun

while

- admin@mydomain.com
- sales@mydomain.com

will be handled normally with your email client.

Please do not hesitate in asking more details!

Comment: What urls would you then put in for the Thunderbird settings for smtp and imap address?

Comment: Also, will you need an extra ssl certificate? http://jeffreifman.com/how-to-install-your-own-private-e-mail-server-in-the-amazon-cloud-aws/setup-client-access/

Comment: The content of the emails handled by Mailgun will be accessible through the API. The rest of the settings will be as per your provider.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This should be in the mailgun documentation under the Routes section. Took me a while to realize why the routes were failing.

Comment: What service for receive mails do you suggests? I mean, what email clients? Because I have read a tutorial that suggests to don't install my own email server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your MX record settings for your subdomains in your DNS control panel.